# Update app on play store so only new users can download- is it possible?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I wrote an android app in Kotlin around a few years ago. I would like to now convert it to dart/flutter. I guess I have to write a new app for this in dart/Flutter with exact same functionality.

The problem I can't figure out is what will happen to the existing users? I guess as soon as they update all their data will be lost because the DB will be new in my flutter app.

So I want to know if there is a way to update the app, but only new installs can access that and it does not update on existing users.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this might be to upload the Flutter app as a new app on the Play Store and delist the current one, but this could upset users who have the current version installed if they want to take advantage of new functionality, and you may still need to spend time supporting them. Plus if you eventually do decide to migrate the old users you'll need to convince them to download the new app rather than just update. Have you considered migrating the data in the old DB to the new DB using [platform channels](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)?

Comment: Thanks @Chris. This seems a little out of my league. Delisting current app might mean losing all the SEO work done for that app.